# Data binding update values in child component with abstracted changes?

Tags: angular

If a value is too abstracted does that prevent the value from updating in the component it is passed to? For example: `<some-component [someValue]="someValue"></some-component>` and if we define `someValue` in the parent component to be `someValue = otherValue` and we say `otherValue = someOtherValue` will changing `someOtherValue` update `someValue` in the child component? I'm having some issues and wondering if this could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is primitive data type (string, number, boolean) then change will not trigger but if it is a object then yes changing in property of object will trigger changedetection.

Hope it will help

Comment: I'm testing this now let's see if it helps.